# How to check object is valid

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I have my class object, if i have this object on the different places and when i deleted and initialized this object to NULL i want this object would be NULL on all the other places. It is possible?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "QDebug"

class A {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(int a, int b) {
        this->m = a;
        this->n = b;
    }

    int m;
    int n;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

B* temp = new B(1, 2);
B* b1 = temp;
B* b2 = temp;

delete temp;
temp = NULL;

qDebug() << b1->x << b2->x; //its print 421312312 -2131231231

return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: What you need are smart pointers.  Particularly shared and weak pointers

Comment: What you need is [`QPointer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html), if you are going to use Qt-based classes

Comment: @DmitrySazonov QtObject-based classes, otherwise correct.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov no i dont have a Qt based classes. I just only have my custom class.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `this->` syntax.  Assign variables directly.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i dont understand..

Comment: In your constructor, use `m = a;` not `this->m = a;`.  Better would be an initialization list.

Comment: Can you explain what is problem this-> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With std, it would be something like:

```
auto temp = std::make_shared<B>(1, 2);
std::weak_ptr<B> w1 = temp;
std::weak_ptr<B> w2 = temp;

temp.reset();


auto b1 = w1.lock();
auto b2 = w2.lock();
if (b1 && b2) {
    qDebug() << b1->x << b2->x;
}
```

Comment: And what is difference?

Comment: Similar to `QSharedPointer` and `QWeakPointer` but in std.

Answer (score 0):

Thank @NathanOliver and all.

I am using QSharedPointer.

```
    QSharedPointer<B> obj = QSharedPointer<B>(new B(1, 2));

    obj.clear();

    B* t = obj.data();

    if (t)
        qDebug() << t->m << t->n;
    else {
        qDebug() << "NULL";
    }
```

now t is NULL. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Is it better to use C++ smart pointers instead of Qt. You don't need if-else there, because your `obj` will be always `nullptr` there.

Comment: That won't work. One pointer must be owning, the other ones must be weak, and you need to lock the weak pointers prior to use. You haven't really tried it out.